# Как сделать кнопке ободок?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно создать кнопку вот с таким ободком

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В целом такое легко сделать при помощи тени внутри фигуры ([box-shadow: inset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: solid #e99;
  background: #e99;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #fff, 
              0 5px 5px #0004;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>Text on button</div>
```